# Move the “linked questions” and “related questions” sections up the page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, related-questions, homepage

The “linked questions” and “related questions” sections are very important to the **usability of the site**, and help to **engage new users** by directing them to other questions of interest.

It is hard to see the linked and related questions as they are below the:

- Side Advert
- The Site Stats
- The Tags
- The “asked and viewed stats”

**New users** looking at questions with few answers may never scrolled far enough down the page to see these sections.   A new user has no **reason to believe** that there will be anything useful in the side bar below the adverts.

The “tagged” panel could be removed when not filtering by tag(s) by putting the “ x3 “ on the tag list at the bottom of the question.  And/Or using two columns for the list of tags, so reducing its height.

The “Asked” and “Viewed” stats could be reduced in size and added to the bottom of the question

The “Site Stats” could be removed form question/answer pages and just shown on question list pages, and then shown if there is no advert to show on a question page.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

ok, well we went another direction.. and things moved up -- see **related** below.

[image]

Comment: I think the "Related" quesions section is still to far down the page.